# Second quantization interaction operator - what does the integration variable $\mathbf{r}$ represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, many-body, second-quantization

In some texts (see [1],[2],[3]) the two particle interaction operator is defined as:
$$
V_{int.} =\frac 1 2\int d\mathbf{r}d\mathbf{r'} V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r')} \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r'}) \psi(\mathbf{r})\psi(\mathbf{r'}).
$$

Whereas other texts (see [3], [4]) explicitly order the terms (suggesting they don't commute?) like:

$$
V_{int.} = \frac 1 2\int d\mathbf{r}d\mathbf{r'}  \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r'}) V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r')} \psi(\mathbf{r})\psi(\mathbf{r'}).
$$

Do both orderings mean the same thing? Is $V$ an operator or a complex number? And is $\mathbf{r}$ a coordinate or actually an operator $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, because for first quantized standard representation $\hat{V} = \sum_{i<j} V(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j)$ I assume the $\mathbf{r}_i$ are formally operators ($\mathbf{\hat{r}}_i$) just like in $\hat{V}(\mathbf{r}) $ for the standard single particle case?

Also, how should one think about operators like this: is it better to think of the operator integrals as the limit of the discrete sum in the sense that "*we dont evaluate the integral until it acts on a Hilbert space ket*", or do the integrals get 'evaluated' first hence removing the integration dummy variables $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$ from the expression? Surely, it cannot be this since then we have "no operators remaining"?

---

References:

- [1] - [equation (1.5.6c)](https://gdenittis.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/second-quantization.pdf)
- [2] - [equation (1.71) in INTRODUCTION TO THE MANY-BODY PROBLEM, University Of Fribourg, SPRING TERM 2010](https://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/jbrader/Many_body.pdf)
- [3] - [equation (51) in Second Quantization, Jörg Schmalian](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/ss2016_tkm2/second_quantization.pdf)
- [4] - [page 43 in Lecture Notes for Quantum Matter, Steven H. Simon](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/QCM2022/QuantumMatter.pdf)
- [5] - [equation (101) in Manybody wave function and Second
  quantization, Ming-Che Chang](https://phy.ntnu.edu.tw/%7Echangmc/Teach/SM/ch01.pdf)

I believe this question is related [Does $T(x)$ represent a $c$ number or an operator in the second quantization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/657877/).

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right-hand sides of the given formulas
the $\psi^\dagger$ and $\psi$ are operators,
and $V$ is just a complex number
(depending on $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$, which are coordinates,
not operators).

So both formulas mean the same thing. Only the ordering of the
operators matters.
You may want to write the operators with a $\hat{}$ to make it more clearly:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{V}_{int.}
 &=\frac 1 2\int d^3r\ d^3r'\ 
 V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})
 \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r'})
 \hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r'}) \\
 &= \frac 1 2\int d^3r\ d^3r'\   
 \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r'})
  V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r')}
 \hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r'})
\end{align}$$

(And by the way: the differentials in the integrals are volume elements, not vectors.
Therefore I wrote $d^3r$ and $d^3r'$, instead of $d\mathbf{r}$ and $d\mathbf{r}'$.)

The equations above are operator equations.
That means they are true for any state $\left|u\right>$
acted on by the operators. Like this:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{V}_{int.}\left|u\right>
 &=\frac 1 2\int d^3r\ d^3r'\ 
 V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})
 \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r'})
 \hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r'})
 \left|u\right> \\
 &= \frac 1 2\int d^3r\ d^3r'\  
 \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r'})
  V(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r')}
 \hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r})\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{r'})
 \left|u\right>
\end{align}$$

So, first the operators act on a state $\left|u\right>$,
and then the integrals are evaluated.

Comment: What do the integrals of the operators mean (e.g. see second part of question)? Are the integrals evaluated before or after the operator "acts on a state"?

Comment: @user246795 see my addition to the answer

Comment: It is common to choose to write the volume elements as if they were vectors. Funny that you are specifically making a comment about not doing that.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Are you writing the volume elements to specifically separate them from the $\mathbf{r}$ in the field operators? I am still not 100% sure when the $\mathbf{r}$ changed from operators '$\mathbf{\hat{r}}$' in the discrete case to simply label vectors in the continuous case.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm writing $d^3r$ to make it dimensionally correct.
$d^3r$ has dimension of length$^3$, not length$^1$.
And it is just a number, not a vector of 3 numbers.